# how to understand TypeScript intersection via keyof

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface Person {
   name: string;
}

interface Lifespan {
   birth: Date;
   death: Date;
}

type PersonSpan = Person & Lifespan; 

type K = keyof PersonSpan;   // type K = "name" | "birth" | "death"

let prop: K = "name";  // ok 

let obj: PersonSpan = {   // compile error, missing birth and death properties
   name: "John Smith"
}
```

if I want to understand type intersection via `keyof`:

the key of this object instance`{ name: "John Smith" }` is `name`, which matches `keyof PersonSpan` which is `"name" | "birth" | "death"`, it is valid to do `let prop: "name" | "birth" | "death" = "name";`

so as long as the object has one of those three properties should be valid, why it still need to have all properties to be assignable to `PersonSpan`?

Comment: but it does not match PersonSpan, you could use `Partial<PersonSpan>`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? When you do `type PersonSpan = Person & Lifespan; ` you're telling you want both the property of Person and Lifespan, that's why you're getting that error, since no property is optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, when you define a type using an intersection & of two or more types, the resulting type will have all the properties from each of the intersected types. In this case, PersonSpan is defined as the intersection of Person and Lifespan, so an object of type PersonSpan must have all the properties from Person and Lifespan.

Even though keyof PersonSpan results in "name" | "birth" | "death", it doesn't mean that any object with just one of those properties is valid for PersonSpan it means that this type K you initialised is the union of property names of PersonSpan. You can access those properties using the keys "name", "birth", or "death" on an object of type PersonSpan also maybe what you are looking for is Partial type which makes all of the props optional:

```
let obj: Partial<PersonSpan> = {  
   name: "John Smith"
}
```

Comment: well done chat gpt. You should include that `Partial<PersonSpan>` would make it valid maybe.